# How to get gradle to output dependency hash for each dependency

Tags: java, gradle, bitbucket-pipelines

I am seeing, for the first time in my life, a situation where

`gradle compileJava check` runs fine locally but when I try to run the same commands with bitbucket pipelines I get `NoSuchClassDefError`

I do `gradle user-login-server:dependencies` locally and on pipelines and the versions for the artifacts I suspect are identical

So the only explanation I can come up with is that the actual artifacts are different.

Hence: How can I force gradle to output the hash of every dependency so I can trackdown what's going wrong?

Comment: Not just hashes might be suspicious. Are you sure that locally and remotely you are running exactly same JDK?

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz Wielkie Dzieki za odpowiedź. Proszę popatrz [tutaj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339943/gradle-build-local-works-in-docker-container-it-doesnt-why/45351085#45351085) 
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop across the jars and print out a hash like so.

```
task printDependencyHashes() {
    def hash = { File file ->
        def md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5')
        file.eachByte(1024 * 4) { buffer, len ->
            md.update(buffer, 0, len)
        }
        return md.digest().encodeHex().toString()
    }

    doLast {
        configurations.compileClasspath.each { println "${it.name}: ${hash(it)}" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a slight modification to account for the fact that I have a directory full of jaxb files that get generated. other than that, you win.